# Problem getting volume of assembly in Abaqus by python script

Tags: python, abaqus

I need to find the volume of a shell model in Abaqus by python scripting before analysis, hence before the .odb file is available.

I know this is possible in CAE by the Query tool with Mass properties. This should also be possible by scripting with `getMassProperties()['volume']` (e.g. `mdb.models['Model'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties()['volume']`). However, this is the problem, since this does not work properly.

If I just use `getMassProperties()` in the command window I get the following result:

```py
>>> mdb.models['MainModel'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties()
{'volume': None, 'massFromMassPerUnitSurfaceArea': None, 'area': 11975.8517821263, 'volumeCentroid': (None, None, None), 'warnings': (ZERO_DENSITY, MISSING_SECTION_DEFINITION), 'momentOfInertia': (None, None, None, None, None, None), 'centerOfMass': (None, None, None), 'mass': None, 'areaCentroid': (-1.16289328510922e-16, -2.06018531309507, 37.4999999999999)}
```

Hence no volume is found.

However, if I first use the Query tool and Mass properties in CAE, and find the volume to 0.00286 (see image), then the above scripting works (the value is somehow stored).
[image: Query tool to find volume]

After use of the Query tool, then the result is

```py
>>> mdb.models['MainModel'].rootAssembly.getMassProperties()
{'volume': 0.063598067897832, 'massFromMassPerUnitSurfaceArea': None, 'area': 11975.8517821263, 'volumeCentroid': (0.0, -2.01943926098974, 37.5), 'warnings': (MISSING_DENSITY, ZERO_DENSITY, MISSING_SECTION_DEFINITION), 'momentOfInertia': (None, None, None, None, None, None), 'centerOfMass': (None, None, None), 'mass': None, 'areaCentroid': (1.02383557403908e-16, -2.06018531309506, 37.4999999999999)}
```

hence, now the volume is available!!!

The problem is, that the `getMassProperties()` only works after user interaction in CAE, hence it is not suitable for use in a python script without user interaction.

How can the above problem be solved? Or how can the volume be found by another scripting solution?

(The shown model is a simple example, however the actual model has advanced geometry, hence the volume is not straight forward to compute by simple math).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't recall if the use of the query tool is reflected in the .rpy file, but if so, it's possible that would reveal additional commands/functions/etc that could explain how the volume was determined.

Comment: I just checked, but the query tool is unfortunately not reflected in the .rpy file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following:

```
assembly=mdb.models[modelName].rootAssembly
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=assembly)
```

before:

```
weight=assembly.getMassProperties()['mass']
```

Comment: Why should he do that? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! [answer]

Comment: I also encountered this problem and searched for a long time, but I didn't find an answer. Then I tried in Abaqus and found that the assembly must be displayed before you use query tools. So I guessed the code "session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=assembly)" is needed. Then I verified the code and found that it works.